# Can´t read properly from string array

Tags: c

So for this program i get a bnary file as input, and I have:
1)Read a Unique binary key
2)After reading said Binary Unique Key, I have to read the characters in front of it (ex: Find Binary Key->Print chars(upper case and lower case only) and print integers.

However this is not working as supposed to. I am leaving below what I got so far. Any help would be kindly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void splittingFunction(FILE *filePtr, long fileLength)
{
    long binaryInteger, aux;
    char *auxPtr;
    int i=0, n,count=0, beginFlag, endFlag, j;
    long arrSize=0;
    char *buffer=(char*)malloc(fileLength+1);
    if(!buffer)
        printf("Out of Memory");
    n=fread(buffer, fileLength, 1, filePtr);
    buffer[fileLength+1]='\0';
    //for(i=0; i<=fileLength; i++)
    //  printf("%c",buffer[i]);

    arrSize=fileLength/8;

    printf("\nARRAYSIZE=%d", arrSize);
    char **arr=(char**)malloc(arrSize*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(char *)malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    }



    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
       strncpy(arr[i], &buffer[i*8], 8);
       arr[i][8]='\0';

    }
    /*for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        puts(arr[i]);
    }*/

    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        binaryInteger=strtol(arr[i],&auxPtr,10);
        if(binaryInteger==10001||binaryInteger==11001||binaryInteger==11101||binaryInteger==11111||binaryInteger==10111||binaryInteger==10011)
        {
            i++;
           while(checkType(arr[i])!=0||checkType(arr[i])!=1||checkType(arr[i])!=2)
            {
                aux=strtol(arr[i],&auxPtr,10);
                printf("%c", convertBinaryToDecimal(aux));
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nCOUNT=%d",count);

    free(buffer);
    free(arr);
}
```

**checkType Function**

```
int checkType(char *str)
{
    long binaryInteger;
    int decimal;
    char *ptr;

    binaryInteger=strtol(str, &ptr, 10);

    decimal=convertBinaryToDecimal(binaryInteger);

    if(decimal>=65 && decimal<=90)
    {
        return 1; //upper case
    }
    else
    if(decimal>=48&&decimal<=57)
    {
        return 0; //integer
    }
    if(decimal>=97&&decimal<=122)
    {
        return 2; //lowercase
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

**convertBinaryToDecimal Function**

```
int convertBinaryToDecimal(long n)
{
    int decimalNumber=0,i=0, remainder=0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        remainder=n%10;
        n/=10;
        decimalNumber+=remainder*pow(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimalNumber;
}
```

Comment: "However this is not working as supposed to." What exactly is happening? How does it differ from what you want? We need more to go on than that.

Comment: For 0 index isn't this out of range? `buffer[fileLength+1]='\0';`

Comment: It is out of range by `1`, The file will be read into indexes `0 -> filelength-1` making *nul-termination* proper at `buffer[fileLength]=0;` However, since you are reading a binary file, there is no guarantee that there are not *nul-characters* (e.g. zeros) contained within the file that would cause `buffer` to contain multiple strings. It further appears you are dividing buffer into `8` equal arrays. Without more specificity, it is hard to know if that is correct. Regardless, you don't need multiple `for` loops to allocate and copy, you can do that in one.

Comment: In addition to David: ceil rounding for `int` division can be done with a simple trick: `arrSize = (filelength + 7) / 8;` i.e. adding to the divider 1 less then divisor. (You see similar expressions often when any kind of memory/address alignment has to be considered.)

Answer (score 0):

Without having your data file, it is impossible to be sure what your logic is intended to be, but even without it we can offer some help. As noted in the comments, you are attempting to *nul-terminate* `buffer` out of range by `1`. You indexes for `buffer` will be `0 -> filelength - 1` making termination proper at `buffer[filelength] = 0;`

Next, don't use magic numbers in your code, if you need constants, define them, e.g.

```
#define ARRSZ   8 /* if you need a constant, define one */
#define BASE   10
```

Don't use numbers where characters are intended. It makes your code more difficult to read, e.g.

```
if(decimal>=65 && decimal<=90)
```

Instead, use `'A'` and `'Z'` and open the spacing of your code a bit to make it more readable (especially for older eyes), e.g.

```
if (decimal >= 'A' && decimal <= 'Z')
```

The remainder of the errors, lack of validations (or just needed cleanup) in `splittingFunction` are outlined with comments in the code below. The final bit of logic beginning with `while ( checkType (arr[i]) != 0 || ...` makes no sense and will fail for punctuation characters and symbols as your default `else` in `checkType` returns `0` just as it does for `'0' - '9'` -- perhaps `else` should `return 3`? Here are the noted issues with `splittingFunction`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>  /* for strtol conversion validation */

#define ARRSZ   8   /* if you need a constant, define one */
#define BASE   10

void splittingFunction (FILE *filePtr, long fileLength)
{
    int count = 0, i, j;  /* j unused, but suspect intended for while logic */
    long binaryInteger, aux, 
        arrSize = (fileLength + 7) / ARRSZ; 
    char **arr = malloc (arrSize * sizeof *arr), 
        *auxPtr = NULL,
        *buffer = malloc (fileLength + 1);

    if (!buffer) {  /* validate buffer memory allocation */
        perror ("malloc error - buffer");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* validate read of fileLength bytes */
    if (fread(buffer, 1, fileLength, filePtr) != fileLength) {
        perror ("fread failed.");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer[fileLength] = 0; /* nul-terminate - questionable... */

    printf("\nARRAYSIZE = %d\n", arrSize);

    if (!arr) {  /* validate arr pointer allocation */
        perror ("malloc error - arr ptrs");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {     /* for each in arrSize */
        arr[i] = malloc (ARRSZ + 1);    /* allocate ARRSZ + 1 bytes */
        if (!arr[i]) {                  /* validate arr[i] storage */
            perror ("malloc error - arr[i]");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memcpy (arr[i], &buffer[i * ARRSZ], ARRSZ); /* copy ARRSZ bytes */
        arr[i][ARRSZ] = 0;                          /* nul-terminate */
        puts (arr[i]);                  /* output string (optional) */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        errno = 0;                          /* reset errno for validation */
        binaryInteger = strtol (arr[i], &auxPtr, BASE);
        if ((a[i] == auxPtr) || errno) {    /* validate conversion */
            perror ("strtol a[i] converison");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (binaryInteger == 10001 ||       /* check defined values */
            binaryInteger == 11001 || 
            binaryInteger == 11101 ||       /* ALL represent       */
            binaryInteger == 11111 ||       /* NON-printable chars */
            binaryInteger == 10111 ||       /* (decimal 17 - 31)   */
            binaryInteger == 10011 ) {
            // i++;     /* DO NOT INCREMENT FOR LOOP COUNTER WITHIN LOOP */
            count++;    /* ( it looks like you intended count++ ) */
            /*
             * This logic makes no sense !
             * aux will equal binaryInteger (again)
             * there is only one arr[i], 'while' not needed, 'if' ?
             */
            while ( checkType (arr[i]) != 0 ||
                    checkType (arr[i]) != 1 ||
                    checkType (arr[i]) != 2 ) {
                /* ?? this is binaryInteger again ?? */
                // aux = strtol (arr[i], &auxPtr, BASE);
                printf ("%c", convertBinaryToDecimal(aux));
            }
        }
    }

    printf("COUNT = %d\n",count);

    free(buffer);
    for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)   /* you must free storage for each arr[i] */
        free (arr[i]);
    free(arr);                      /* then you free arr pointer */
}
```

(**note:** C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants)

In `convertBinaryToDecimal` there is no need to require the inclusion of `math.h` in order to call `pow (2, i)`. Why? `pow (2, i)` is a simply *left-shift* by `i`, e.g. instead of `decimalNumber+=remainder*pow(2,i);`, simply use `decimalNumber += remainder << i;`. Example:

```
int convertBinaryToDecimal (long n)
{
    int decimalNumber=0,
        i=0, 
        remainder=0;

    while (n)
    {
        remainder = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        decimalNumber += remainder << i;
        ++i;
    }
    return decimalNumber;
}
```

Look things over, especially the added validations, and let me know what you intended in your last section of `splittingFunction` and if you have any additional questions and we are happy to help further.